# How to Show Mongo Queries in IRB

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mongoid, irb

I used mysql, rails4 in project

if I don't know real sql statement

I Using  **to_sql**  in irb or rails console

```
2.1.0 :006 > Model.all.to_sql
 => "SELECT `model_name`.* FROM `model_name`"
```

but I dont't know what is show mongo query in irb or rails console.

how to show mongo query in IRB?

Comment: Try like this in rails console, "Model_Name.where(:name => "RoR")"

Comment: @RubyOnRails ehm.. I want show query String, like 'to_sql' statement :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883178/get-raw-mongo-db-query-expression-that-mongoid-generate-it