# Get raw mongo db query expression that mongoid generate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to get the mongoid generated mongo query expression how to do it ?

e.g. this is the mongoid syntax

```
History.where(report_type: params["report_type"]).order_by(ts:1).only(:ts).last
```

I want to have the method, such as `to_sql`, to get the native query expression so that I can apply it on Mongo console.

Answer (score 7):

MongoDB doesn't really have a query language like SQL so you can't get the whole thing in one nice compact piece. You can, however, get the pieces.

This:

```
History.where(report_type: params["report_type"]).order_by(ts:1).only(:ts)
```

builds a `Mongoid::Criteria`. That's more or less the Mongoid version of the underlying query. You can extract the query by calling `selector`:

```
q = History.where(report_type: params["report_type"]).order_by(ts:1).only(:ts)
q.selector
# { 'report_type' => whatever_was_in_params }
```

the ordering by looking at `options[:sort]`:

```
q.options[:sort]
# { 'ts' => 1 }
```

and the `fields` are in `options[:fields]`:

```
q.options[:fields]
# { 'ts' => 1 }
```

Comment: That is amazing. I think you just made my life a lot easier.

Comment: While the answer is nice, this is awful. All this mess Mongoid/MongoDb ... OMG.